# Where the bitbucket source code after clone

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new with bitbucket. after I clone the scource, step by step, I cannot find where my source code is in my hard drive. i follow this [help](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Clone+your+Git+repository+and+add+source+files).
Please help me find the source code folder

I use **windows 8.1**

Comment: Which OS are you using? If it is Linux or OSX the folder should be in your home folder. Do not know about the windows though (although it probably is the same...)

Comment: @Goran I use windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

If you executed the `git clone` command in the folder `~/repos` and your repository is named `repo` the cloned repository, if the clone command was successful, will be in `~/repos/repo`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source code in `C:\Users\<UserName>\<folder name created by git>`

Comment: There you go - home folder :)